# included MySQLStore.h but HAVE_MYSQL not defined error (quickfix VS2015 c++)

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2015, quickfix

i using quickfix c++ 
when i want store data to mysql db and using MySQLStoreFactory class(include with mysqlstore.h) it show top error 
i also included mysql include path and libs but didn't change 
so any Idea?? [image]

Comment: Post the error you are getting for people to help.

Comment: Format it and post it in your query rather than in the comments.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NEOkL.jpg

Comment: i uploaded the image in link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!

### ***i downloaded new MYSQL server LIB***

put library address `additional library directory dependency` for tradeclient project

---

change name of libmysql.lib to libMySQL.lib in mysql server folder

---

add libMySQ.lib  name in linker ->input->`additioanl dependency`

---

put mysql include in C/C++ include directory

---

put "libmysql.dll" in release folder
build and run in cmd

---

and all Done !